# How to use EF6 (DB-first) with ASP.NET core web application(.NET framework 4.6.1)?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am building asp.net core web application using full .NET framework 4.6.1 template like this-

[image: 1]

My project.json shows-

```
  "frameworks": {
    "net461": { }
  },
```

I wanted to use **EF6 (not EF core)**, hence install entity framework using NuGet package manager using this command-

```
Install-Package Entityframework
```

Project.json added this entry-

```
"EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
```

When I am trying to create a DBcontext and model using below Command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=XXXXX;Database=XXXXXXX;User Id=XXXXXXX;password=XXXXXXX" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -t TABLENAME
```

It throws below error:

> Scaffold-DbContext : The term 'Scaffold-DbContext' is not recognized
>   as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>
> Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
>   the path is correct and try again.

As I understand (since I have Powershell v3.0 and .NET core 1.0.1), rest of the EF tools and dependencies are missing in my project.json. So **which are tools and dependencies I need to add in my project.json to use EF6 (not EF core)?**

Some of the options I can see are like below. But not sure which one is right for EF6

"EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer":

[image]

"EntityFramework.SqlServer":

[image]

"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc2-final"

[image]

Comment: You may need to upgrade to powershell 5.  See [this github issue comment](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5376#issuecomment-220090141) about the same error.

Comment: I don't have any problem with Scaffold-DbContext. I am confuse here how to use EF6 (not EF core) in ASP.NET core web application(.NET framework 4.6.1)?

Comment: you have already read this nice official getting started article https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/data/entity-framework-6.html  ,and noticed "For example, Scaffold-DbContext is only available in Entity Framework Core" do you

Comment: Thanks @ergen for clarification that **Scaffold-DbContext is only available in Entity Framework Core**. I was on wrong track. But my main question still remains open - _how to create DBcontext and model with EF6 in ASP.NET core web application(.NET framework 4.6.1)?_

Comment: @GretelHendricks were you ever able to figure this out? I'm in the same boat but not finding any answers

Answer (score -1):

I didn't get what you mean by using core in .net but if you are targeting you project to old .net you need to install compatible version.

For .net 4.8 following package version will work:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Version 3.1.25
```

Comment: Not sure if Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer is also needed. 
If yes use, Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Version 3.1.25
Also your provider in scaffold should be System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: You can use Entity Framework 6.0 with .net Framework and ASP.NET core, the 3 are compatible. But scaffold-DbContext is not available in EF 6